# Real Time Plot for Core Plot - Data Usage

Tags: ios, graph, plot, real-time, core-plot

Is there is a way to plot a live graph in iOS core plot without saving the data as a CSV file? The data is being read from the server and I saw some examples, where they save the data that is incoming as csv file. Can I just input the data and plot as and when it comes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data input issue in Real Time plotting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047463/data-input-issue-in-real-time-plotting)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can store the incoming data any way you want so long as it's available to the plot datasource when needed. Core Plot will cache the plot data internally so you can discard your copy once the datasource has loaded everything.

Comment: but the data i get is like 10000 lines of data. is that still possible then?